# dotnet ef run with --configuration causes MSB4006

Tags: c#, entity-framework, msbuild, .net-core

I have .NET Core application. I am trying to execute

`dotnet ef --configuration Release database update`

to generate SQLite Entity Framework database (both restore and publish commands work flawlessly). This fails with

`Project.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets(4,5): error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "GetEFProjectMetadata". [C:\Project\src\Project\Project.csproj]
Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project. If you're using custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.`

for which I was unable to google anything.

It does not occur if I execute

`dotnet ef database update`

which confuses me because the project's debug/release configuration are default.

What confuses me even more is that this command

`dotnet ef --configuration Debug database update`

does not work either, so this is ultimately related to the use of `--configuration`. Note that I use `--configuration Release` with `publish` command and there is no problem with it.

I have tested this on Windows 10 system with MSVS2017 installed, as well on a clean Windows 7 system where I installed the latest 64-bit .NET Core SDK. Both systems behave exactly the same.

The project file does not define any BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath.

The project dependencies on EF in project file are as follows:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
```

and

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
```

The error is present even if I remove most of the stuff from the project file.

Comment: I just opened an issue for this on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8399

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this will be fixed in 2.0, but the current workaround is to also specify

```
--framework
```

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8399

In my instance it was

```
--framework netcoreapp1.1
```

Comment: I just noticed I liked to the issue that was opened from this question